# After completing the output,console application exits.. How to make it ask for input again?

Tags: c++

I created a console application in VStudio 2015.... and after it executes properly,asks for input and shows the output, it says press any key to continue.
I want the program to ask again for the input...
Heres the code :-

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "iostream"
   #include "stdio.h"
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
          int a, b, n;
          cout << "Enter the number of lines:";
          cin >> n;
          for (a = 1; a <= n; a++)
          {
                 for (b = 1; b <= a; ++b)
                 {
                           cout << a;
                 }
                 cout << "\n";
          }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: You've written two loops in your program. If you want your program to ask for input again then you need a third loop that goes around the code you have already written. That's how you get C++ programs to do things multiple times, write loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another loop:

```
int a, b;
int n = 1;
while (n > 0)
{
    cout << "Enter the number of lines:";
    cin >> n;
    for (a = 1; a <= n; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; ++b)
        {
            cout << a;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: And leave that loop exactly when??

Comment: Could set a condition. Ex: while(n != -1). Basics.

Comment: Basics of course, but the more appropriate condition would be `n <= 0`. Be precise, real world oriented and concise, when answering please!

Comment: while(n > 0) seems more appropriate. I wouldn't want while(n >= 0), don't want to loop if input is 0.

Comment: Sorry I actually meant `n > 0`.

Answer (score -1):

Put a third loop on top of your code.

```
 int a, b, n;

     while(true)
     {
          // here you need to figure out how to break loop 
          // I mean how to go out from it. It depends on your 
          // purpose 

          cout << "Enter the number of lines:";
          cin >> n;
          if (n==-1)
          {
             // I assume n should be larger than 0 for your purpose.
             break;
          }
            for (a = 1; a <= n; a++)
          {
                 for (b = 1; b <= a; ++b)
                 {
                           cout << a;
                 }
                 cout << "\n";
          }
     }
```

**Edit**

Although I do not think its necessary, as you can see, someone thinks that using n<=0 is better choise than n==-1. Its your call. You can either change it, or just type an information which states that which number the user should give as an input in order to terminate the program.

Comment: _`if (n==-1)`_ shouldn't that be something like `if (n <= 0)` going  along with your assumption?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you can write whatever constrain you want, I just give an example

Comment: The more appropriate condition would be n <= 0. Be precise, real world oriented and concise, when answering please!

Comment: I couldnt see any difference between n<0 and n==-1 . In both cases, user have to know that it should give an negative number to the program for terminating it. Furthermore, even if you're right it shouldn't be n<=0 but maybe n<0

Comment: So you'd consider `0` is a valid input, seriously? Also how does that condition (`n==-1`) handle `-2` as input actually??

Comment: I edited my answer, if you're not satisfy, please write your own answer.

Comment: Its up to you,  I cannot say anything about it

Comment: I'm not going to write an answer for questions that can be trivially solved, and I'm close voting for lack of research. But even if you provide a trivial solution, make up something useful, instead of proposing an infinite loop!

Comment: Do I have to write complete and debug free solution ? In my answer I've already said that **"constrain depends on your purpose"** If you think my solution is not good enough, you're able to write your own or downvote my answer or  put a comment under my answer. I accept all of these. But after that, continuing to write comments that are irrelavent from the question just makes me annoying. You made your point, I said okey its your idea I respect it. Please stop now